# Mock Setup It.any for any expression return fixture value

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, fixtures

I would like to do a Mock Test and define as below :

```
public interface INode {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string NodeName { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<INode> Childrens { get; set; }
}
    
public interface INodeQuery {
   public IEnumerable<INode> GetNodes();
}
public class NodeProcessService {
   readonly INodeQuery nodeQuery;
    
   public NodeProcessService(INodeQuery nodeQuery) {
       this.nodeQuery = nodeQuery;
   }
   public string currentNodeName { get;set;}

        
   public int Handler() {
       var getNode = nodeQuery.GetNodes()
                .Select(p => p.Childrens.FirstOrDefault(c => c.NodeName == currentNodeName))
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p != null);
    //do something...
   }
}
```

In the test, I want to do the Mock nodeQuery which any expression will be return fixure value, such like this:

```
public NodeServiceTests()
{
   fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
   nodeQuery = fixture.Freeze<Mock<INodeQuery>>();
   sut = fixture.Create<NodeProcessService>();
}

[Fact]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    var fakeNode = fixture.Create<INode>();
    nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault(It.IsAny<Func<INode, bool>>())).Returns(fakeNode);
    
    var result = sut.Handler();
}
```

but I've got error as below code :

```
    nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault(It.IsAny<Func<INode, bool>>())).Returns(fakeNode)
or 

nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault()).Returns(fakeNode)
```

Can you advice how to do it , which I want to mock nodeQuery.GetNodes() whatever any expression func return a single fixture value.

Thank you for all advise,

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault()).Returns(fakeNode) 
will get : System.NotSupportedException: 'Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault<INode>()'

nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault(It.IsAny<Func<INode, bool>>())).Returns(fakeNode)
will get
System.NotSupportedException: 'Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault<INode>(It.IsAny<Func`2>())'

Comment: It will be helpful to edit the question and add these details there...

Comment: You should mock the behavior of only `nodeQuery.GetNodes()`. `FirstOrDefault` method is not part of INodeQuery interface so you can not mock its behavior.

Comment: How can I return the single node which ignore any expression func ?

Comment: You can not bypass or mock the execution of `.Select(p => p.Childrens.FirstOrDefault(c => c.NodeName == "main")).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null);` So you need to mock the behavior of `GetNodes` to return a list of nodes which will satisfy the `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` conditions...

Comment: Ok, Thank you, but I have a issue that the sut function c.nodename is matching with variable but I have an idea not sure if nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes().FirstOrDefault(c.NodeName == It.Any<string>()).Returns(fakeNode)
will try about it

Comment: please look at the updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to escape or ignore parameters passed to `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` method. That wouldn't be possible until you mock the behavior of `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` method of `IEnumerable<INode>`.

It is easier to setup the mock data which can give you desired result even after execution of the real `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` methods.

Following is the mock data I came up with which you can set as a result of `GetNodes` method.

```
[Fact]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    var node = new Node { Id = 1, NodeName = "parent" };

    var child = new Node  {Id =11, NodeName="main" };
    node.Childrens = new List<INode>{child};

    var nodes = new List<INode> {node};

    nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes()).Returns(nodes);

    var result = sut.Handler();
}
```

---

Edit : Based on your feedback about `currentNodeName` not being static in `FirstOrDefault` method, I suggest following test approach.

You should not try to fake or setup LINQ methods. They are extension methods. They do not belong to any interface or class. So faking them or setting up their bhehavior will not work at all.

Also you are testing the code of `NodeProcessService` class. You should not fake any part of it's code. Only dependency behavior should be faked. If you  fake the `NodeProcessService` code, that means you are not actually unit testing real code and its behavior but you are testing the fake code.

You have currentNodeName property in `NodeProcessService` class. And value of this property is used in `FirstOrDefault` criteria of `p.Childrens`.

So when you run the test, you should set `currentNodeName` property value and use the same value in creating fake nodes too. This will make sure that the logic of `Handler` method is executed as exactly it is written.

```
// this test is to call Handler method and it should return the 
// children nodes whose name is "main".
[Fact]
public void TestChildNodesReturnWhenPresent()
{
    var currentNodeName = "main"; //this can be any thing you want.

    sut.currentNodeName = currentNodeName;

    var node = new Node { Id = 1, NodeName = "parent" };

    var child = new Node  {Id =11, NodeName= currentNodeName };
    node.Childrens = new List<INode>{child};

    var nodes = new List<INode> {node};

    nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes()).Returns(nodes);

    var result = sut.Handler();

   Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}

// this test is to call Handler method and it should return null 
// when children not with specified name does not exist.
[Fact]
public void TestNullReturnedWhenChildreNodeNotPresent()
{
    var currentNodeName = "main"; //this can be any thing you want.

    sut.currentNodeName = currentNodeName;

    var node = new Node { Id = 1, NodeName = "parent" };

    var child = new Node  {Id =11, NodeName= "childNode" };
    node.Childrens = new List<INode>{child};

    var nodes = new List<INode> {node};

    nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes()).Returns(nodes);

    var result = sut.Handler();

   Assert.IsNull(result);
}
```

Comment: Hi, nodename is not static variable, how to mock it ?

Comment: There is nothing static in my code too... what's the confusion? Why do you think you need to mock NodeName?

Answer (score 0):

As Chetan wrote in the comments, you should mock only `GetNodes()`:

```
nodeQuery.Setup(s => s.GetNodes()).Returns(new[] { fakeNode });
```

The mock will return a collection consisting of only the fakeNode.

Comment: But can I return the single one but not a collection ? because I want to ignore all predicate expression and return the single node